# How to come back to application and execute statements after finishing intent

Tags: android-intent

I have written an android code which calls an intent from application say A. after finishing intent I want to come back to A app and execute some more lines. Please help me out.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(R.layout.send_mail);

        pdf=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pdf);        
        pdf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddLoc.class);                         
                            startActivity(in);
                            et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Code to be executed after activity
                            et2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            et3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            new getMasterLocation().execute();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Activity Result](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)?

Comment: I tried it. But it's not executing lines written in onActivityResult()